# "Истекает срок годности" у file_id Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть бот знакомств на python 3.10, библиотека telebot, бд пока что sqlite3, при регистрации пользователь заполняет анкету и отправляет фото, бот file_id этого фото сохраняет в бд и какое то время можно по этому file_id отправлять анкеты с фото, но через неопределенный для меня срок этот file_id как я понимаю перестает быть действительным, и при попытке отправить анкету и фото с этим file_id получаю ошибку:
**telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"**

Как хранить фото так чтоб они были постоянными? Что можете посоветовать в этой ситуации?

Comment: Нет, он не перестает быть действительным. Кроме того, по file_id - это рекомендованный способ тг повторного использования файла. Но доступен файл по file_id только в пределах одного бота. Каким образом вы его используете?